# for loop to extract month from data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have around 4000 rows of dates I need to extract the month (number) from.  I know you can do this with a formula (Month(date)) I have beat my head against this keyboard and have finally given up.  nothing seems to be working like it has been on another macro I and copying from ha. I would post some sample code but it would probably just confuse you...as its doing to me lol.

pretty much I have a start date and need to enter the month in the column beside it

```
Start date                    Month
1/25/2014 3:00 pm              1
2/20/2014 2:00 am              2
1/5/2014 1:00 pm               1
```

I'm sure you get the picture.

or I would be ok with entering the month formula in the first cell then auto fill it down....either way is fine with me

thanks and sorry for the basic question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=MONTH(A1)
```

To fill a **range** of cells in column **B** with **VBA** I would use:

```
Sub FillIt()
    Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=MONTH(A1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, I know that.  but to autofill it down with macro...it would be something like this right

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Comment: I see what I did now on my row count...gaahhh its the little things...thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here, try putting this code into a vba module then run it by clicking macros. It will prompt you for column input, then do everything else automatically.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim column As String
    Dim cell As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    column = InputBox("Enter column" & vbNewLine & "Example: D")

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In Range(column & "1:" & column & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        With Cells(cell.Row, cell.column + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = Month(cell.Value)
        End With

    Next cell

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Invalid column"
End Sub
```

- To open the VBA editor from excel, press alt+f11
- On the left side of the VBA Editor there is a "project" hierarchy.
- In the hierarchy, right click the project you're working onto create a module.
- Paste the code in the module.
- Go back to the worksheet with the dates, press alt+f8, select test
  and click run

Comment: not what i was looking for but is a way for users to run this macro is the column ever changes.  thanks for your input!

Comment: which part was i off on? o.o

Comment: having them input the column

Comment: aha ^.^, just replace the column = inputbox("...") line with column = "A"